# unable to fetch data from json file in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I'm new in angularjs,i'm trying to load data from my json file on view. json file have some list of patients. 
But does not get showed on my view

here is my 'patient.json' file

```
[
{
    "id": 0, 
    "first_name": "John", 
    "last_name": "Abruzzi", 
    "middle_name": "Kewan",
    "DOB": "12/03/1935", 
    "ssn": "254-2342-42",
    "sex" : "Male",
    "country" : "USA",
    "city" : "Greater New York",
    "phone" : "1234124822",
    "military_branch" : "Army",
    "zip" : "08675",
    "guid" : ""
}, 
 {
    "id": 1, 
    "first_name": "Peter", 
    "last_name": "Burk", 
    "middle_name": "S",
    "DOB": "31/06/1945", 
    "ssn": "342-9876-54",
    "sex" : "Male",
    "country" : "USA",
    "city" : "New York",
    "phone" : "3346573924",
    "military_branch" : "FBI",
    "zip" : "25643",
    "guid" : ""
  }, 

 {
    "id": 2, 
    "first_name": "Neal", 
    "last_name": "caffery", 
    "middle_name": "Sam",
    "DOB": "28/02/1988", 
    "ssn": "420-4204-20",
    "sex" : "Male",
    "country" : "USA",
    "city" : "New York",
    "phone" : "676554323",
    "military_branch" : "Air Force",
    "zip" : "26531",
    "guid" : ""
  },
  ]
```

here is my controller.js

```
var patientApp = angular.module('patientApp', []);

 patientApp.controller('PatientListCtrl',['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.jsonp('/json/patients.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.patients = data;
 })
 });
 $scope.orderProp = 'id';
 }]);
```

Here is my 'index.html' file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="patientApp">
<head>
<title>Patient Management</title>
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="PatientListCtrl">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>ID</tr>
        <tr>First Name</tr>
        <tr>Last Name</tr>
        <tr>SSN</tr>
        <tr>DOB</tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<div data-ng-repeat="patient in patients">
    <table>
        <tr>{{patient.id}}</tr>
        <tr>{{patient.last_name}}</tr>
        <tr>{{patient.first_name}}</tr>
        <tr>{{patient.SSN}}</tr>
        <tr>{{patient.DOB}}</tr>
    </table>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

I think i'm missing something.
plz help me ,thanks in advance.

Comment: What you get if you do console.log($scope.patients)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using jsonp. It will not work jsonp is a work around to get data from diferent domain sources what it does is creates a javascript tag in your page this javascript will load an execute a function that you already have define in your page. so returning the json will not execute the function. Will not work.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

It looks like you don't have a problem of different domain requests because the url that you are trying to access is /json/patiens.json so I can assume you are trying to load it from the same domain. If that is the case $http.get is the way to go.

One more thing your code needs to run from a web server. If you created this test page and you are trying to load it from the filesystem, my friend you are out of luck will never work. You can not make ajax calls to file:///

In the case you are running it from a web server check the mime type. It could be that the mime type in the response header is incorrect and the browser can not parse the document.

If you are using a decent browser (anything other that IE) you have very reliable good debugging tools check if your code is making a request to the server. And check what are you getting back including the headers specially the mime type. If you are using windows a great tool is fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$http.jsonp`, use `$http.get`

```
$http.get('/json/patients.json').success(function (data) {
   $scope.patients = data;
});
```

Check out this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZxafeslnhmdjMxFrzuzA?p=preview)

Comment: I found that plunker,showing the the file's data,but when I try on my machine it's not showing single record.